# How does Pytorch's `autograd` handle non-mathematical functions?

Tags: python, pytorch

During the course of my training process, I tend to use a lot of calls to `torch.cat()` and copying tensors into new tensors. How are these operations handled by `autograd`? Is the gradient value affected by these operations?

Comment: `torch.cat` is a function in the mathematical sense (when restricted to tensors of a given shape – but such restrictions stemming from Python's typesystem's poor expressiveness are necessary for pretty much all functions you'd want to handle with PyTorch's autograd). What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: (Hint: concatenating elements of R^m and R^n to obtain an element of R^(m+n) is a function in the mathematical sense. From here you can recover what `torch.cat` does, with the above caveat.)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, `cat` is a mathematical function. For example we could write the following (special case) definition of `cat` in more traditional mathematical notation as

[image]

The Jacobian of this function w.r.t. either of its inputs can be expressed as

[image]

Since the Jacobian is well defined you can, of course, apply back-propagation.

In reality you generally wouldn't define these operations with such notation, and a general definition of the cat operation used by pytorch in such a way would be cumbersome.

That said, internally autograd uses backward algorithms that take into account the gradients of such "index style" operations just like any other function.